# How to run a windows container inside Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have managed to install docker on windows and am able to run docker from my ubunto bash prompt of the WSL but when I try to pull or run a windows image from docker hub I get the following error:

```
root@DESKTOP-J9B5HJG:~# docker info  -f '{{.OSType}}/{{.Architecture}}'
linux/x86_64
root@DESKTOP-J9B5HJG:~# docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows:1809-amd64
Error response from daemon: manifest for mcr.microsoft.com/windows:1809-amd64 not found
root@DESKTOP-J9B5HJG:~#
```

I have also enabled experimental features and am exposing the daemon.

[image]

Comment: Does it happen for Windows containers only? Does other commands like `docker run` work?

Comment: @Biswapriyo yes, only when trying to pull or run the windows image, all other images work fine

Comment: I tried it in Linux. Same issue. It looks like the issue in Microsoft containers only.